# Copying files from Multiple Folders Where the File Name is a part of the folder

Tags: shell, powershell, file, copy

'I am trying to copy multiple files from multiple folders into another folder.  The folders have a part of the file name in them.

For example - 
I want to copy all the files that have the name "Phone" or "cell" and the serial number as a part of the file name.  Each sub folder has the serial number as a part of the folder name.

```
C:\shared\112\products\112.phone blah blah.txt
C:\shared\112\products\112.my cell.txt
C:\shared\113\products\113.ugly phone.txt
C:\shared\113\products\113.the cell.txt
C:\shared\114\products\114.pretty phone.txt
C:\shared\115\products\115.phone lazy.txt
C:\shared\115\products\115.celly cell.txt
```

The problem is there are 20,000 serial numbers so I want to set up a list of serial numbers and pull the file based on a set of serial number.
Here is my script but it is not pulling anything.'

```
$FirstSearchlist = @(“112”, “113”)
$SecondSearchlist = @("phone","cell")

$dirArray = @("c:\Shared\")
$NotFound = "Not Found"

cls
function Recurse([string]$path) {

    $fc = new-object -com scripting.filesystemobject
    $folder = $fc.getfolder($path)

    foreach ($i in $folder.files) {

        [string]$FullPath = $i.Path
        [string]$FileName = $i.Name
        foreach($first in $FirstSearchlist) {
            if ($filename.ToUpper().Contains($first.ToUpper())) {
                foreach($second in $SecondSearchlist) {
                    if ($filename.ToUpper().Contains($second.ToUpper())) {
                        Write-Host $Fullpath
                         Copy-Item $Fullpath -Destination "C:\Shared\Phones" -Recurse
                                 }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($i in $folder.subfolders) {
        Recurse($i.path)
    }
}

function main() {

    foreach ($i in $FirstSearchlist){
        $NewFolder = $dirArray + $i
        foreach($SearchPath in $NewFolder) {
            Recurse $SearchPath
        }
    }

}

main
```

Comment: I created the suggested file structure and files, and running it only produces a 0 KB file called Phones with no type at C:\shared

Comment: So, when your done, you want a copy of all the files in a single target folder?  That is, "C:\shared\112\products\112.phone blah blah.txt" would be copied to "C:\shared\112.phone blah blah.txt", correct?

Would I be correct if I said, instead, you want all files that have ("phone", or "Cell") and ("112" or "113") in the file name?

Might be easier to pull then entire folder, then filter out what you want (depending on the number of actual criteria).

Also, it considered bad form to a function that calls itself.  It often causes a stack overflow as the OS tries to keep track each call.

Comment: Actually I want it to copy to "c:\shared\112.phone blah blah.txt"    And yes to your second question.  It may be easier to pull the entire folder but there is a folder for each serial number.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me testing with the example set provided (but note in my testing C:\Shared is empty, may want to adjust down your folder tree depending):

```
Function Get-FileMatches($Filter){
    $fileMatches = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Shared" -Recurse | ? {$_.Mode -notmatch 'd' -and $_.Name -match $Filter -and ($_.Name -match $SecondSearchlist[0] -or $_.Name -match $SecondSearchlist[1])}
    return $fileMatches
}

Function Run-Script() {

    $FirstSearchlist = @(“112”, “113”)
    $SecondSearchlist = @("phone","cell")
    $allMatches = @()

    $phonesFolderExists = Test-Path "C:\Shared\Phones"

    if($phonesFolderExists -eq $False)
    {
        New-Item -Path "C:\Shared\Phones" -ItemType Directory -Force
    }

    foreach($listItem in $FirstSearchList) {
        $currentMatches = Get-FileMatches -Filter $listItem
        if($currentMatches -ne $null)
        {
            foreach($item in $currentMatches)
            {
                $allMatches += $item
            }
        }
    }

    if($allMatches -ne $null)
    {
        foreach($item in $allMatches)
        {
            Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination "C:\Shared\Phones"
        }
    }
}

Run-Script
```

Comment: Thanks trebleCode.  Unfortunately it didn't work for me.  I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: Of the example set, what gets returned, error or otherwise?

Comment: It just repeats the script over and over again.

Comment: Have you stepped through it in VS Code or PS ISE to see why on your system? With the test structure provided it runs once and completes. Happy to help